# jqvmap - how to correct any country map?

Tags: html, svg, jqvmap

I am using clickable jqvmap world map. I found few maps not correctly drawn.

Can anyone help me to understand how I can correct the coordinates of any country map?

I tried changing some numbers of path tag but it went wrong.

Is there any tool which can help me to get value as I draw any map?

Is there any other more precise/correct world map without Atlantic & Antarctica? Can I replace them with jqvmap?

Comment: You can open the map in Inkscape if you want to draw in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by [Lexib0y](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3143634/lexib0y), [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/) is a good option. Thanks [Lexib0y](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3143634/lexib0y)!